# Counting the numbers between $1$ and $1,000,000$ whose digits sum to $30$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

> What's the number of numbers between $1$ and $1,000,000$ whose digits sum is $30$?

So I thought of this as a stars and sticks problem, so in the case you have $35\choose 5$ numbers whose sum is $30$. But obviously this number of numbers includes many overlaps (if for instance the requested sum was $8$, then $80=800=8000=134=143=431$ etc.). How do I get rid of the overlaps (inclusion-exclusion)?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Just a note: If each digit would be random from $\{0, \ldots, 9\}$ then the sum of $6$ digits would approximately be distributed as $\mathcal{N}(27, 99/2)$ leading to about $\approx 51,750$ out of every $1,000,000$ numbers with sum $30$. This is pretty close to the actual number.

Comment: (The lazy Mathematica-answer is $50,877$.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn’t overlaps: it’s restricting the values to the range from $0$ through $9$. You’re looking for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to the equation

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=30\tag{1}$$

with the added requirement that $x_k\le 9$ for $k=1,\dots,6$: each of those solutions defines one of the numbers that you’re trying to count, and *vice versa*. The number of solutions **without** the upper bound restriction is, as you say,

$$\binom{30+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{35}5\;.$$

However, some of those solutions require ‘digits’ greater than $9$. Start by counting the solutions in non-negative integers to $(1)$ that have $x_1\ge 10$. Those are clearly in one-to-one correspondence with solutions in non-negative integers to

$$y_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=20\;,$$

where $y_1=x_1-10$, and you know how to compute their number. Call that number $n_1$. There are just as many solutions to $(1)$ that violate the upper bound on $x_2$, just as many again that violate the upper bound on $x_3$, and so on, so a better approximation to the solution to the original problem is

$$\binom{35}5-6n_1\;.$$

Of course this overcorrects, since it’s possible for a solution to $(1)$ to violate two of the upper bound constraints at once. You’ll have to calculate the number $n_2$ of solutions that have $x_1\ge 10$ **and** $x_2\ge 10$ and then add back the appropriate multiple of $n_2$. And since it’s actually possible to violate as many as three of the constraints at once, you’ll have to make one further [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) correction.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the insight. I didn't think of the upper boundry! Now, as for you corrections. Would $n_1={20\choose 5}$? Also, I didn't understand your last paragraph. How can two of the upper bound constraints be violated at once? Or in short, I didn't understand the last paragraph idea :/

Comment: @ohad: Calculating $n_1$ is a stars-and-bars problem: $n_1=\binom{20+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{25}5$. The solution $x_1=x_2=15$, $x_3=x_4=x_5=x_6=0$ violates the upper bound constraints on both $x_1$ and $x_2$. The $6$-‘digit’ number $(11)23(12)11$ violates the constraints on $x_1$ and $x_4$.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I understand now why there can be two and even three violations on that constraint, but how does that reflect on the number of numbers? Thanks and sorry to bother you so much.

Comment: @ohad: It means that when we subtract $6\binom{25}5$ to get rid of the solutions that exceed one of the bounds, each solution that exceeds **two** bounds get subtracted twice and therefore counted $-1$ times in the total $\binom{35}5-6\binom{25}5$. We want to count it $0$ times, so we have to add it back in. There are $\binom{15}5$ solutions to $(1)$ that exceed the bounds on $x_1$ **and** $x_2$ (why?), and there are $\binom62$ pairs of variables, so there are $\binom62\binom{15}5$ solutions to $(1)$ that violate at least two constraints and have to be added back in. But if you check, ...

Comment: ... you’ll find that every solution that violates **three** constraints (and there are some) has been counted once in $\binom{35}5$, $3$ times in $6\binom{25}5$, and $3$ times in $\binom62\binom{15}5$ (why?), for a total of $1-3+3=1$ time. But we don’t want to count those solutions, so we need to subtract them from $\binom{35}5-6\binom{25}5+\binom62\binom{15}5$. And that’s the last such correction that’s needed, since it’s impossible to get a total of $30$ with $4$ or more variables violating the constraint.

Comment: First of all, many many gratitudes! I'm pretty bad in this, but there is only one thing I didn't understand. Why indeed the solutions that violates three constraints has been counted once in $35\choose 5$, 3 times in $6$ $25\choose 5$ and 3 times in $6\choose 2$ $15\choose 5$? The rest I understood, and it makes lots of sense. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @ohad: The term $\binom{35}5$ counts every solution to $(1)$, so for instance it counts $(10)(10)(10)000$. That solution violates constraints on $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$, so it gets counted $3$ times in $6\binom{25}5$, once for each of those variables. It violates constraints on both members of the pair $\{x_1,x_2\}$, the pair $\{x_1,x_3\}$, and the pair $\{x_2,x_3\}$, so it gets counted $3$ times in $\binom62\binom{15}5$, once for each of those pairs.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. You have helped me to a very great extent and I thank you for that!

Comment: @ohad: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that it helped.

Answer (score 5):

One looks for the number $N$ of integer solutions of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^6n_i=30,\qquad 0\leqslant n_i\leqslant9.
$$
Thus, $N$ is the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in the polynomial
$$
\prod_{i=1}^6\sum_{n_i=0}^9x^{n_i}=\left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^6.
$$
To compute $N$, note that
$$
(1-x^{10})^6=\color{red}{1}-\color{red}{6}x^{10}+\color{red}{15}x^{20}-\color{red}{20}x^{30}+o(30),
$$
and that
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}=\sum_{k=0}^{30}\color{green}{{5+k\choose5}}x^k+o(30),
$$
where $o(30)$ denotes terms of order at least $31$, hence
$$
N=\color{red}{1}\cdot\color{green}{{5+30\choose5}}-\color{red}{6}\cdot\color{green}{{5+20\choose5}}+\color{red}{15}\cdot\color{green}{{5+10\choose5}}-\color{red}{20}\cdot\color{green}{{5+0\choose5}}=50877.
$$

Comment: If I remember correctly, this is the first exercise in Polya-Szego's treatise.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Can you find the number of integer soloutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=30$$ such that  $0\leq x_i\leq 9$ for all $i$. Use generating functions!

Comment: After using this hint.. inclusion-exclusion should work fine, right?